# `if constexpr` vs `if` in light of compiler optimization and code performance

Tags: c++, c++17, if-constexpr

Consider a function template `func` that is very performance critical. It can be instantiated with `T=Type1` or some other type. Part of the function logic depends on `T` it is instantiated with.

One can either explicitly use a `if constexpr` (Code B) or use a vanilla `if` instead (Code A), while compiler *probably* optimizes the code.

However, I wonder, how the implementation without `constexpr` (Code A) is any different? Isn't the compiler **capable** of detecting which branch of `if` (in Code A) to use at compile time while instantiating? **Can** it still (for Code A) generate a less efficient code?

Code A. **Without** `if constexpr`:

```
template<class T>
void func(T argument)
{
    // some general type-independent logic
    if (std::is_same<Type1,T>::value)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }
    // some general type-independent logic
}
```

Code B. **With** `if constexpr`:

```
template<class T>
void func(T argument)
{
    // some general type-independent logic
    if constexpr (std::is_same<Type1,T>::value)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }
    // some general type-independent logic
}
```

Both codes A & B compile, as `do something` and `do something else` are well-formed for any `T`.

There are some similar-sounding questions:

- [Why is `constexpr if` needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972666/constexpr-if-vs-if-with-optimizations-why-is-constexpr-needed) – this one answers when `constexpr` is required.
- [Difference between `if` and `constexpr if`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43434491/2452869) – just lists the differences

The aforementioned questions do not answer if Code B is preferable to Code A for some reason (when both branches are well-formed anyway).

The only advantage I see would be to tell the programmer explicitly that this `if` is compile-time; however, I would say the conditional expression is self-explanatory.

Comment: Primarily opinion based. There are arguments for either Code B being "better" than Code A, or Code A being "better" than code B. It all depends on the specific, and precise, definition of what "better" means. The only time you can objectively state that "B" is better than "A" is when "A" results in undefined behavior, and "B" is not. Everything else is up for grabs.

Comment: With B there will be no branch in the compiled code, so you've got that going for you.  Which is nice.

Comment: For the same reason the `override` keyword exists, it's desirable to actually have a compilable, but discarded branch that serves as a canary should something else, in some other header file gets changed that would result in the discarded branch no longer compiling, and raising an alert as to the issue at hand.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The `override` [contextual] keyword exists because it's very easy to _hide_ when you intended to _override_ by simply getting some part of the signature wrong. I have no idea what benefit you're talking about in the rest of that comment? Mind you, the motivation of `if constexpr` is very much that the discarded branch _does not_ and _cannot_ compile - and we're trying to avoid that.

Comment: I cannot explain this any better without giving a long example, but sometimes you /do/ want a compilation error if, as a result of some change that's /not/ in the immediate vicinity, the aforementioned "immediate vicinity" no longer compiles, instead of being suppressed inside a `if constexpr`. Suffice to say, that the capsule summary is that one way to avoid runtime bugs is to make arrangements to (to the maximum extent possible) turn runtime bugs into compilation failures.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`if constexpr` is not intended about optimization. Compilers are very good at optimizing away a branch that is `if (true)` or `if (false)` (since we're talking about constant expressions, that is what it boils down to). Here is a [godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Lbc8I4) of the example in OP - you'll note that both gcc and clang, even on `-O0`, do not emit a branch for a simple `if`.

`if constexpr` is all about ensuring that only one branch of the `if` is *instantiated*. This is hugely important and valuable for writing templates - because now we can actually write conditionally compiling code within the body of the same function instead of writing multiple artificial functions just to avoid instantiation.

That said, if you have a condition that is a known constant expression - just always use `if constexpr`, whether or not you need the instantiation benefit. There is no downside to such a decision. It makes it clearer to readers that indeed this condition is constant (since otherwise it wouldn't even compile). It will also force the evaluation of the expression as a constant (a [slight variant](https://godbolt.org/z/lEUIeu) leads gcc to emit a branch at `-O0`, thought not at `-O1`), which with the coming addition of `is_constant_evaluated()` may become more important in the long run (possibly even negating my opening paragraph).

---

> The only advantage I see would be to tell the programmer explicitly that this if is compile-time; however, I would say the conditional expression is self-explanatory.

To address this specifically, yes, `std::is_same<X, Y>::value` is "self-explanatory" that it is a constant expression... because we happen to be familiar with `std::is_same`. But it's less obvious whether `foo<X>::value` is a constant expression or whether `foo<X>() + bar<Y>()` is a constant expression or anything more arbitrarily complicated than that.

It's seeing `if constexpr` that makes the fact that it's compile-time self-explanatory, not the content of the condition itself.

Comment: The big advantage of if constexpr when "not needed" is you get an *error* if you are wrong about it being consteval.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an example to @Barry 's explanation: The use is primarily for writing templates. Consider the following:

```cpp
template <class T>
auto get_value() 
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
        return 1
    } else {
        return 2.0;
    }
}
```

You can note that, if the template parameter is `int`, the return value is determined to be `int`, while it is `float` when the template parameter is not `int`. You will see that this does not work with non-constexpr if statements, because at instantiation, all returns of a function must have a common type, which the former does not have. The only other way of achieving this is to use c++20 contraints, or `std::enable_if` to overload the function based on the template parameter.

Comment: _while it is `float` when the template parameter is not `int`_ Hmm... I would expect it's **`double`** or `int`

Comment: @Scheff'sCat The example is very contrived. I just demonstrate the principle.