# Why do I need constexpr in recursion with parameter packs

Tags: c++, templates, if-constexpr

I have a simple recursive function to print each argument from a parameter pack

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void printArgs(T first, Args... rest) {
    std::cout << first << " ";
    
    if constexpr (sizeof...(rest) > 0) { // doesn't compile without constexpr
        printArgs(rest...);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

int main() {
    printArgs(1, 2, "hello");

    return 0;
}
```

**Q1:** Why do I need `constexpr` in the `if` for the program to compile?
**Q2:** Shouldn't the condition be `sizeof...(rest) > 1`? Because if the size is `1` and I call `printArgs` again, then wouldn't `rest` be empty? (is it ok for it to be empty?)

I saw similar questions, like ["constexpr if" vs "if" with optimizations - why is "constexpr" needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972666/constexpr-if-vs-if-with-optimizations-why-is-constexpr-needed), but I don't see how those answers relate to my case.

Comment: With an ordinary (non-constexpr) `if`, the first branch would need to be compilabe also for an empty parameter pack. But there is no function definition to be callable for `printArgs()`.

Comment: @DanielLangr why would it need to be compilable for an empty pack?

Comment: Imagine what would happen if you do `printArgs(1)` then `Args... rest` would be empty and only first would have a value. The `else` branch should not be needed

Comment: Because a regular `if` controls flow at runtime, so at runtime that flow has to exist. I.e. compiled from *something*.

Comment: [if constexpr is all about ensuring that only one branch of the if is instantiated.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54545744/12002570)

Comment: fwiw, I dont see that the dupe helps OP. They could be aware of the dupe and still have the same misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll start with the second Q, because the answer to that also explains Q1.

> Q2: Shouldn't the condition be `sizeof...(rest) > 1`? Because if the size is 1 and I call `printArgs` again, then wouldn't `rest` be empty? (is it ok for it to be empty?)

Your mistake is to count `T` for `sizeof...(rest)`. But if you call `printArgs(onlyOne)` then `T` is deduced from `onlyOne` and `Args` is empty, and `sizeof...(rest)` is `0`. Your function can be called with 1 (`T first`) plus zero or more, (`Args... rest`), arguments.

> Q1: Why do I need constexpr in the if for the program to compile?

If you remove the `constexpr` you get the following [error](https://godbolt.org/z/xazfGan3a):

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'void printArgs(T, Args ...) [with T = const char*; Args = {}]':
<source>:8:18:   recursively required from 'void printArgs(T, Args ...) [with T = int; Args = {const char*}]'
<source>:8:18:   required from 'void printArgs(T, Args ...) [with T = int; Args = {int, const char*}]'
<source>:15:14:   required from here
<source>:8:18: error: no matching function for call to 'printArgs()'
    8 |         printArgs(rest...);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
<source>:4:6: note: candidate: 'template<class T, class ... Args> void printArgs(T, Args ...)'
    4 | void printArgs(T first, Args... rest) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~
<source>:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:8:18: note:   candidate expects at least 1 argument, 0 provided
    8 |         printArgs(rest...);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

Because on the last recursion only 1 argument is passed to `printArgs` and `rest` has no elements. In that case `printArgs(rest...)` fails to compile because (see above) your function can only be called with 1 or more. `if constexpr` results in the false branch being discarded and the part where you call `printArgs()` is never instantiated.

Answer (score -1):

Also you don't have to use explicit recursion, from C++17 onward you can use a fold expression.

The following code will output `1, 2, hello`

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename First, typename... Args>
void printArgs(First&& first, Args&&... rest) 
{
    std::cout << std::forward<First>(first);

    //https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold
    // the part before ,... will be repeated/expanded
    // each time with one argument
    ((std::cout << ", " << std::forward<Args>(rest)),...);
}

int main() 
{
    printArgs(1, 2, "hello");

    return 0;
}
```