# if constexpr vs if with constant

Tags: c++, optimization, constexpr, if-constexpr

As shown in this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972666/constexpr-if-vs-if-with-optimizations-why-is-constexpr-needed), if both of `if` branches are valid, there's no difference between:

```
const int foo = 5;
if (foo == 5)
{
    ...
}
else 
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
const int foo = 5;
if constexpr (foo == 5)
{
    ...
}
else 
{
    ...
}
```

in terms of optimization (in both cases the `else` branch would not be instantiated). So if the expression in vanilla `if` can be checked at compile time (it involves a `const` or `constexpr`) - the optimizations work here as well.

I previously thought that that was the purpose of `if constexpr`, but I am wrong. So is there a use case of `if constexpr` other than the case then we may have only one of many `if` branches valid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit contrived example, but consider this:

```
const int foo = 6;
if (foo == 5)
{
    some_template_that_fails_to_compile_for_anything_else_than_5<foo>();
}
```

This will not compile even though the body of the `if` will never be executed! Still the compiler has to issue an error. On the other hand, this

```
const int foo = 6;
if constexpr (foo == 5)
{
    some_template_that_fails_to_compile_for_anything_else_than_5<foo>();
}
```

is fine, because the compiler knows at compile time the value of `foo` and hence does not bother about the body of the `if`.

Answer (score 7):

`if constexpr` is a bit confusing in this regard.

It's not there to ensure that unreachable branches are optimised out (that usually happens anyway).

It's there to allow us to write code that *may not compile* without breaking the build if the compilation error depends on a template parameter. It's all about template instantiation.

So:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T x)
{
   if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
   {
       // Code that's semantically invalid for non-int can go here!
       // Naive example (though obviously this works with some non-int types too)
       x += 42;
   }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not extend to a condition that doesn't depend on T, so if you wanted to do this:

```
constexpr bool DoThings = false;

void foo()
{
   if constexpr (DoThings)
   {
      static_assert(false);
   }
}
```

… the assertion will still fire; [your program is ill-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38304847/560648). It's not necessarily easy to come up with a real-world example of when you'd get hit by this, but it's still arguably unexpected.

In general, try not to think of `constexpr` as having anything to do with "optimisation". It's about build phases; it is a tool that sometimes let you enforce some things "happening" in the realm of the template metahackerer. In practice, this generally implies compile-time execution, but it's not directly related to "optimising things out", and you shouldn't start sprinkling `if constexpr` everywhere just to try to remove "dead" branches from your compiled executable: your compiler is doing that anyway (and why do you have dead branches in your code?).