# error: request for member ‘..’ in ‘..’, which is of non-class type ‘..’

Tags: c++, c++11, is-same

I started a simple big integer library project, and decided to take it up again. But I can get over this error I am getting.

```cpp
template <typename T>
bigint(T a)
{
        // Constructor for bigint passed
        // Let's call this 'A'
        if (std::is_same<T, bigint>::value)
        {
            this -> n = a.n;
        }

        // Check if passed argument is a float
        else if (std::is_same<T, float>::value or std::is_same<T, double>::value)
        {
            // Type-caste to lose fractional part
            this -> n = std::to_string((long long) a);
        }

        // Check if passed argument is a string
        else if (std::is_same<T, const char*>::value or std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
        {
            this -> n = a;
        }



        // Straight cast for integers
        // Let's call this 'B'
        else
        {
            this -> n = std::to_string(a);
        }
}
```

Now when I call the constructor for an `int` or any other data-type, the first `bigint` constructor `A` is called, when `B` should be called, even though the types are different.

```cpp
>>> bigint a(100);
bigint.h:42:18: error: request for member ‘n’ in ‘a’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   42 |    this -> n = a.n;
      |                ~~^
```

Comment: `if (std::is_same<T, bigint>::value)` --> `if constexpr (std::is_same<T, bigint>::value)`

Comment: Did you assume `if constexpr (std::is_same<T, bigint>::value)`? IMHO all your code would be much shorter more clear if your write a copy and overloaded converting constructors separately using initializing lists.

Comment: It's not at all obvious to me that this should be a single templated constructor and not multiple distinct overloads. That being said, unless you use `if constexpr` all branches of the `if` must be compiled even if they aren't run. So when you instantiate `bigint::bigint<int>`, it needs to be able to compile the first branch even though `is_same<int, bigint>` is `false`.

Comment: `bigint(T a)` is missing a return type

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, judging by the `is_same` checks, `bigint` is the class name, thus, its a constructor.

Comment: I hope this is helpful :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877523/error-request-for-member-in-which-is-of-non-class-type

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["constexpr if" vs "if" with optimizations - why is "constexpr" needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972666/constexpr-if-vs-if-with-optimizations-why-is-constexpr-needed)  (the answer here provides example of a very similar situation to what you're seeing)

Comment: @Learner That question is about a similar error message, but the cause and remedy are completely separate from anything in this question. This is not a most vexing parse problem.

Comment: @ChrisMM Thank you! I will read about this constexpr in detail. Just started learning.

Comment: @S.M. I am not sure I understand how to implement initialising lists.

Comment: @NathanPierson Would multiple distinct overloaded constructors be better than a single templated constructor that checks for all types?